# How to split image to 2 parts?

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm a beginner with android. I want to divide a bitmap image into chunks and then display the image in the same way but divided.

Edit:

This code has worked for me

Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking specific programmers questions. People are reluctant to write whole code examples.

Comment: Yes, please ask specific questions.  What you want to do is possible.  What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 13):

Here's some pseudo code, that I hope you can use:

```
Bitmap originalBm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("fileUrl"); // Let's say this bitmap is 300 x 600 pixels
Bitmap bm1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBm, 0, 0, originalBm.getWidth(), (originalBm.getHeight() / 2));
Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBm, 0, (originalBm.getHeight() / 2), originalBm.getWidth(), (originalBm.getHeight() / 2));
```

So, basically - bm1 is the first half and bm2 is the second half. Both will be 300 x 300 pixels.

Comment: http://www.fr4gus.com/2011/03/16/bitmap-crop-en-android/  thank you very much for the reply, i found this one the web.  which would be better