# Splitting screen animation in Android java

Tags: java, android, animation

Is there any way to make an animation where the current page on an android application gets split down the middle and moves to both sides then leading to another page?

Comment: [Looks like you need to use bitmaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116069/animated-screensplitting-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach it:

Create a bitmap of the screen. ([Create image from view/screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095080/create-image-from-view-screen-in-android))

Split the bitmap into 2. ([How to split image to 2 parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234986/how-to-split-image-to-2-parts/7235344#7235344))

Animate the 2 bitmaps.

Comment: Whats the code that will animate it to split, im kind of a noob at animations.

Comment: Translate Animation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276251/how-to-animate-a-view-with-translate-animation-in-android.