# How to split image to 2 parts in Horizontally?

Tags: android, image, split, imageview, horizontal-scaling

I have image which i want to split in to two parts. (Not ImageView)

This image should be equally split and show in image view.

[Hear is a Screen Shoot which i want output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG55O.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split image to 2 parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234986/how-to-split-image-to-2-parts)

Comment: This is answer already tried.